# Is there a way to get phone number of facebook's contacts in Windows Phone 8

Tags: facebook, windows-phone-8, phone-number

My app is getting all phone's numbers from user's contact list. But I saw that the numbers that are from facebook are not showed.

I made a quick research, and all the answers to this questions was the following:

> You can only get friends who authorized your App too since v2.0 - only with an App created before end of April 2014 (v1.0). But it will
>   stop returning all friends after April 2015.
>   You can´t get phone numbers of friends, that was never possible. You can´t even get the phone number of the authorized user.

I know there is some questions about this issue, and I'm not duplicating it, because the answers for all those questions was the same (that I put above).

None said if it was possible get this numbers from another way. Like an facebook API or something... and this I couldn't find in anywhere.

Because other OS like Android and Iphone can get this number doing nothing... I think there is a way to retrieve this number in Windows Phone 8 too...

Can somebody tell if it's possible or should I give up of trying this?

Comment: "like the facebook api"? that answer is exactly about the facebook api. there is no other way, you can´t get phone numbers of facebook contacts. you can get the numbers on your phone with a native app, but NOT from facebook.

Comment: Guess it's not possible... I found this [page](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.2/user) with the fields that I can retrieve from a user, using Graph API from Facebook... and phone number is not on it...

Answer (score 3):

It was never possible to get the phone number via the Graph API.

See

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.2/user#fields